# Поиск и копирование файлов по маске из сервера в папку?

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, поиск

как сделать поиск файлов по маске затем его скопировать из сервера в папку

файл *.dbf начинается с индекса в индексе 4 или 1+- цифры (T_ARM_i_index)дальше идут цифры * только их длина не больше 6-ти цифр, пример dbf файла: 07901306281.dbf

Только я не знаю как сделать поиск по маске, если файл найден то дальше копировать в заданные папки и тд.. :

```
Regex Mask_dbf = new Regex(@"[0-5].dbf$");
foreach (string file in  Directory.GetFiles(SF2_IP_i, $"{T_ARM_i_index}{Mask_dbf}", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) /*string file in files)*/
                            {
                                if (File.Exists(file))
                                {
                                    if (!Directory.Exists(ImportArhivTovar))
                                    {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(ImportArhivTovar);
                                        File.Copy(file, $"{ImportArhivTovar}\\{Path.GetFileName(file)}");
                                    }
                                    File.Copy(file, $"{ImportArhivTovar}\\{Path.GetFileName(file)}");
                                    File.Move(file, $"{T_ARM_i_vpz_Import}\\{Path.GetFileName(file)}");
                                }
```